# Georelation between 2 sets og geojson

Tags: leaflet, point-in-polygon

I have 2 sets of geojson polygons: one for lands and one for buildings. All buildings are built on lands so all building polygons belong to a land polygon but I don’t have the relationship between the 2 sets and I need to build it on the fly in javascript / leaflet.

My 2 sets can be as large as 10000 polygons per set so I need a good algorythm to minimize the computation time. Do you have an idea on how I could do it? For example is there a way to know all leaflet layers at a specific latlng location? This could be a way to build the relation. Thanks for your help!

Sam

Comment: https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanContains

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I had identified that library. But using this solution means 10000 * 10000 intersections to be checked. I fear it could be slow

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a very fast library that helps! It is called geojson-geometries-lookup.